# why doesn't my code work?, how to fix my code?

Tags: reactjs

```
var PropsChildren = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return
        <div>
            { React.Children .map(this.props.children,function(child){
                return <a>{child}</a>;
            })}
        </div>
        ;
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(
    <PropsChildren>
        <span>Hello </span>
        <span>Hello</span>
    </PropsChildren>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: You have a space in `React.Children .map`

Comment: that's not the real problem,remove the space but the code still not work,it throw a error 'Error: PropsChildren.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
 

error = new Error(format.replace(/%s/g, function () {

 '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `()` around the return statement. You could also start the JSX on the same line as `return` to fix this.

```js
var PropsChildren = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
          return <a>{child}</a>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <PropsChildren>
    <span>Hello </span>
    <span>Hello</span>
  </PropsChildren>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```